# How to convert googlenmapv3 address to placeId and panoId using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps-api-3

please is it possible to convert a human readable address to Google placeId or panoId. I would like to use the placeId to on my Google places app.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to convert readable human address to lat/long. Then you can use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) to get placeID.